# Turning text file into dictionary when the same keys appear multiple times

Tags: python, dictionary, text, notepad

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
tomato 7000
potato and pear 8000
prunes 892
tomato 8
carrot 600
prunes 3
```

To turn it into a dictionary that ignores the lines where there are more words (which is what I want, so `potato and pear` are ignored, which is fine), I wrote:

```
with open("C:\\path\\food.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f_skipped:
    result = {}
    for line in f_skipped:
        try:
            k, v = line.split()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            result[k] = v
```

But since there can't be duplicate keys, it takes the value that appears later, so `tomato` and `prunes` have values `8` and `3`, respectively. Is there any way of taking only the first appearance and ignoring the later once?

I thought of keeping my code and just turning the text around (sounds a bit silly) or detecting whether there are duplicate words (the latter is a bit risky since there are lots of rows with many words that I simply wanna ignore anyway).

Comment: What are you expecting to happen with `potato and pear`? Are those each keys, and should each get assigned value `8000`?

Comment: That line is simply ignored by my code, which is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `.get(key)` method of the dictionary will return `None`  if the key doesn't exit otherwise return the value for the key. so you can use it in if condition.
I hope this is what you want by reading your question.

```
filename = "text.txt"
with open(filename, encoding="utf-8") as f_skipped:
    result = {}
    for line in f_skipped:
        try:
            k, v = line.split()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            if result.get(k) is None: 
                result[k] = v

    print(result)
```

### Output

```
py code.py
{'tomato': '7000', 'prunes': '892', 'carrot': '600'}
```

Comment: `if k not in result` would indicate the intent better

Comment: Yeah you are right.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

```
with open('food.txt') as food:
    D = {}
    for line in food:
        t = line.rsplit(' ', 1)
        k = t[0]
        if not k in D:
            D[k] = t[1].split()
    print(D)
```

Comment: Rather than that awkward construction around splitting and rejoing the parts of `line`, why not use `rsplit` instead?